# Mockito @Before method is called after @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

This is my simplified code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockitoSpringBootTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyBean myBean;


    @Before
    private void before(){
        Mockito.when(myBean.getSomeString()).thenReturn("TEST"));
    }

}

@Service
private class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        myBean.getSomeString(); //SmartNull - method is not stubbed yet
    }

}
```

My problem is that I need to stub `MyBean` methods, before any other class which has this object autowired will run `@BeforeClass` method. Right now `@Before` method is executed after `@PostConstruct` of any class which is autowiring this bean (there's more than one).

MyBean is autowired as a mock, but method is not stubbed, so I get: "SmartNull returned by this unstubbed method call on a mock:"

Is there any way to set priority of mocked bean in Spring container initialization ?

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You can't annotate an initializer block. `@Before(){` You're missing a semicolon after `private MyBean myBean`. There's an extra parenthesis on the end of the `("TEST"))` line. Please run your code before you post it.

Comment: Has `myBean` already been autowired when the `@PostConstruct`-method is invoked, or is it still `null` then?

Comment: @isnot2bad yes - it's autowired as mock, but methods are not stubbed yet so smart null is returned

Comment: Does the initMocks() been invoked?

Comment: Yes, but it's inside @Before method, so it's  after PostConstruct method is called (to late)

Comment: Which is as expected. The application context is initialized before the test method can be executed and hence it will construct all the beans. The `@Before` is called right before the test method gets executed and the context has already been initialized. There is nothing you can do to change this when using `@MockBean` like this. You could create a specialized configuration and manually mock the bean and directly register the behavior you want, that would be the only workaround.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `@TestConfiguration` rather than using the `@MockBean` might help to solve this problem.

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class Configuration {
        @Bean
        public BeanToMock name() {
            // return mock object           
        }
    }
```

And annotating the test class with `@ContextConfiguration`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestClassName.Configuration.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most elegant workaround, but you can mock the behavior within a static block. Code in static block is executed before both `@Before` and `@PostConstruct`. I don't think, that mocking using annotations (`@MockBean`) would work, but it can also be done programatically.